# Jquery date picker Next and previous button images are not showing

Tags: jquery

Jquery Date picker prev and next button images are not showing.

Comment: You have to clarify your question. Which jQuery datepicker?

Comment: please post more code and/or information

Comment: Without the source one can only guess what is happening. Post the javascript and html code to get some meaningful answers.

Comment: Which browser(s)?  Have you looked at the page with Firebug?

Answer (score 11):

I'm assuming you're using the jQuery UI datepicker plugin.  It expects the images to be located in an images folder located within the folder containing the jQuery UI CSS file(s).  Check to make sure you have the images located where jQuery expects.